# How can i pass javascript addListener function value to change function inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `addListener` function and `change` function is there. How can I pass `addListener` result to `change` function inside using javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // find pincode
  var input = document.getElementById('location_input');
  var options = {
    types: ['address'],
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: 'in'
    }
  };
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
  var pincode;

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function fun1() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {
        if (place.address_components[i].types[j] === "postal_code") {
          pincode = place.address_components[i].long_name;
          fun2(pincode);
          //alert(pincode);
        } //return pincode;
      }
    }
  });

  $('input[type="checkbox"],#location_input').change(function fun2(val) {
    var ids = ['filter_AFFILIATION_1', 'filter_AFFILIATION_2', 'filter_AFFILIATION_3', 'filter_AFFILIATION_4'];
    var data = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
      if (document.getElementById(ids[i]).checked === true) {
        data['request' + i] = $('#' + ids[i]).val();
      }
    }
    var pincode = val;
    alert(pincode);
    console.log(pincode);
  });
});
```

Here `fun1` and `fun2` two functions. How can i pass `fun1` `pincode` value to `fun2` inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have defined pincode in global scope.
Just use it.
Here `function fun2(val)` val is `Event` object passed to event callback.
And you dont have to use named functions, anon funcs will work as event callbacks.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // find pincode
    var input = document.getElementById('location_input');
    var options = {
        types: ['address'],
        componentRestrictions: {
            country: 'in'
        }
    };
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    var pincode;
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {
                if (place.address_components[i].types[j] === "postal_code") {
                    pincode = place.address_components[i].long_name;
                } //return pincode;
            }
        }
    });
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function (event) {
        var ids = ['filter_AFFILIATION_1', 'filter_AFFILIATION_2', 'filter_AFFILIATION_3', 'filter_AFFILIATION_4'];
        var data = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            if (document.getElementById(ids[i]).checked === true) {
                data['request' + i] = $('#' + ids[i]).val();
            }
        }
        alert(pincode);
        console.log(pincode);
    });
});
```

Comment: I try to calling pincode value to  inside fun2 but i am not getting i am getting an object but how can i identigy pincode value in object. i want make an ajax call both pincode and change function value at a time but i am not getting both values together

Comment: And read https://api.jquery.com/change/ about using callbacks to event.

Comment: I tried above code but i am getting undefined alert

Comment: Here i am trying to get with out checking any checkbox show the pincode inside change function any idea

Comment: here i am targeting pincode text box id #location_input and input[type="checkbox"] both but with out clicking check box i am not getting pincode value inside function2

Comment: You dont have pincode on text input change, because it's change event fires earlier that Autocomplete change event.